# how to set result of executenonquery in intiger

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have the following query-:

```
 SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlHelper.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, "select COUNT(*) from SiteGallaryImage where IsDeleted=1 and  GallaryId=@SiteGallaryImageId",
                 new SqlParameter("@SiteGallaryImageId", galleryId));
```

how can i set the result of this query to intiger.

Comment: Why do you use `ExecuteNonQuery` for a query? What is the benefit of your helper class? They are mostly just introducing nasty issues and making things more complicated (f.e. to use the `using`-statement).

Comment: If it is the old `SqlHelper` class from Microsoft .NET Data Access Application Block which is replaced by the `Database` class (i wouldnt recommend netiher), then use `(int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecuteNonQuery` Method returns the number of row(s) affected by either an INSERT, an UPDATE or a DELETE.

The `ExecuteReader` Method will return the result set of a SELECT.

The `ExecuteScalar` Method will return a single value in the first row, first column from a SELECT statement. This method is to be used when you expect only one value from the query to be returned.

So for a SELECT statement use `ExecuteReader`.

Here in your select statement it return count(*) so it will be a single value so `ExecuteScalar` is apt